# how to stop the event after the ElapsedEventHandler?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am using the Timer in a wpf project.The interval is 5s.
If in the 5 seconds, I want to reopen this timer before 
timer_Elapsed is performed and timer_Elapsed method isn't performed.
How can i do?

```
public main()
{
      Timer timer=new Timer(5000);
      timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
      timer.start();
}
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   timer.Stop();
   Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
   {  
   });
}
```

Comment: i have changed the question.

Comment: Keeping the Timer.AutoReset property set to *true* causes many problems, don't do it.  There's just no point at all in using this timer when you need to call Dispatcher.Invoke(), it is not better than DispatcherTimer().  It is much worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set this `timer.stop()` or `timer.IsEnabled = false;`. Both do not raise its Elapsed Function.

Comment: Then try `timer.stop` or set its `timer.IsEnabled = false;`

Comment: timer.stop can stop the timer,but timer_Elapsed will be taked one time.

Comment: for the first time: timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed); timer.start(); timer_Elapsed will be performed,but i don't want.

Comment: @zhchma: I did `Timer timer = new Timer(5000);timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);timer.Start(); timer.Stop();` . It did not came even once.

Comment: Timer timer = new Timer(5000);timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);timer.Start();  After 2s,how can i stop the timer_elapsed perform.

Comment: Simply call  `timer.Stop();` and elapsed wont fire for even once.

Comment: Thank you, the reason timer_Elapsed is perfomed is i make a new ElapsedEventHandler.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `System.Timers.Timer`. If you want to restart it within the `Interval` before `Elapsed` event occur, call

```
timer.Stop();
timer.Start();
```

Or

```
timer.Enabled = false;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Obviously, to do this the calling code must have access to `timer` variable, so you might need to declare it on class level.

Comment: timer.stop can stop the timer,but timer_Elapsed will be performed. I don't want it performed.

Comment: When timer is stopped the Elapsed event does not occur. That's the sense of making it stop. If you want timer to occur only once - don't call Start() after it, or set timer's AutoReset property. In your question you're talking about "reopen this timer" - didn't you mean restarting it?

Comment: for the first time:                                                                         timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
timer.start();                                                                                                             timer_Elapsed will be performed,but i don't want.

Comment: i am so sorry ,my english is so bad.

Comment: I created several examples for you (`cause I still don't get the problem 100%), maybe one of these options help: http://pastebin.com/emnjWhgi

Comment: sorry,i can't open  pastebin.com/emnjWhgi.

Comment: Thank you,i have solve the problem. And your method is right.